# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined. jQuery loading widget fails

Tags: jquery, widget

I am trying to build a widget in jQuery to handle loading of content to certain divs on a page. The reason I am doing this is to keep my code DRY. I should perhaps mention that I use HeadJS for javascript loading.

This is my widget code:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    $.widget ("my.contentloader", {

        options: {

            loadingMessage: true,

            errorDiv: '#error',

            contentDiv: '#content'

        },

        _create: function () {

            $.ajax ({

                type: "POST", 

                url: self.options.url, 

                data: {limit: self.options.params.limit, offset: self.options.params.offset},

                beforeSend: function (html) {

                    // Check if loading message should be displayed

                    if (self.options.loadingMessage) {

                        $(self.options.contentDiv).html ("<div id='loading'>Loading</div>");

                    }

                },

                success: function (html) {

                    if (self.options.loadingMessage) {

                        $('#loading').remove ();

                    }

                    $(self.options.contentDiv).html (html);

                },

                error: function (html) {

                    $(self.options.errorDiv).html (html);

                }

            });

        },

        _setOption: function (key, value) {

            this.options[key] = value;

            $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply (this, arguments);

    }

    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I include this widget file and jquery on the calling page. Then I use the plugin like this:

```
 $(window).contentloader ({

  url: 'loading/content/url'

 });
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not defining `self` anywhere so you're getting [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) instead and that's

> an object reference to the window object.

and that doesn't have an `options` property. You should be using `this` instead of `self`; if you need to force a particular `this` in your callbacks, then do a:

```
var _this = this; // or 'var that'
```

before defining the callbacks and use `_this` (or `that`):

```
_create: function () {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax ({
        // ...
        beforeSend: function (html) {
            if (_this.options.loadingMessage) {
                //...
```

The presence of `window.self` makes `var self` a bad name choice.